# Is 'console type' of application suitable for my solution? ( C# )

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, csv, windows-server-2012

I just started my internship as dev student.

I need to write a program in C# that will read a CSV productfeed, then parse it, map it and insert OR update this into a SQL Server database.

The program will run on a Windows VPS and has to be executed daily as the CSV will also be updated daily. I have to automate this process.

SO to come to my questions:

**1.** Can I go with a console application? (because I don't need any GUI)

**2.** Will a program like this with nested loops for insert/update crash or be too heavy on the DB as the CSV can contain +100k records?

Any guidance in the right direction is much apreciated

Comment: Does the app need to be running all the time in order to process the feed?  If so, a console app probably isn't the way to go and you should investigate a Windows Service app instead.  You should also look at Bulk Insert for your DB transactions.

Comment: Does not have to run all the time just once a day to add new products that might exist in the updated CSV feed or update any existent products where price or stock might be changed. Does bulk insert also work as bulk update on existing records?

Comment: No, but look here for advice on how to achieve lots of updates.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27933584/how-to-bulk-update-with-sql-server Regarding your app, even if it runs only once per day, if it's a console app somebody would have to start that each day to run it.  If it's a Windows Service, you can leave it running in the background and set a time when you want it to access the feed.

Comment: I should also say, that if you are doing a Windows Service you can schedule it to run in the early hours when nobody is using the system.  In that case DB insert/update performance will likely not be as important.

Answer (score 1):

1. **YES**. You can develop a Console Application indeed. Doing something with Windows Forms or similar (i.e a C# app with a form and a single button with code.) would be a bad idea as you don't need a GUI and would be much harder to automate.

   **What options do you have?**

   - **Console application**: Easy to develop. You can schedule it using Windows Task Scheduler.
   - **Windows Service**: A little bit harder to develop. It is much easier to control if it is running or not.
   - **WCF or Restful Web Service**: Harder to develop but more open if it needs to evolve in the future. Easier to interconnect with other servers as execution can be triggered externally.
2. **NO**, potentially no, although with bad code you can manage to create problems in SQL Server.

**My advice**: If you don't have much time/skills, go for Console App. If you can, create an asynchronous RESTFUL web service implementing GET to see the status of last/current execution, POST to trigger a new execution and return correct HTTP Response codes.

Answer (score 0):

**1. Can I go with a console application? (because i don't need any GUI)**
Yes you can you **Console Application** and Task schedule for run this program daily.
Also you can write **Windows Service** - in this case your program will run in background.

**2. Will a program like this with nested loops for insert/update crash or be too heavy on the DB as the CSV can contain +100k records?**

100K+ rows its nothing for MS SQL. But sure you need write code correct. I will parse its and then Insert in db in multi thread. But it depends on what you need to do.

Answer (score 0):

Technically you could use any application type you want, but If I'm gonna write this application I will pick [Windows Service Application](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d56de412(v=vs.110).aspx) , because you want the application to run repeatedly in an automated way.

and for the performance, I don't think that hitting the database for every record it the best practice here may be you should look for [Bulk Insert.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx)